# Is there any tutorial on how to set up a simple CRUD web app on TomEE using just JPA and JSF?

Tags: jsf, jpa, apache-tomee

I'm a fan of **Tomcat** and would really like to use **TomEE** but having a hard time configuring TomEE why isn't there a simple tutorial explaining step by step, setup of a simple JSF and JPA CRUD web app on TomEE.

If there is I really haven't found it, so please share it here.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://uaihebert.com/full-web-application-with-tomcat-jsf-primefaces-jpa-hibernate/) an example. I think it will work for you

Comment: that's Tomcat not TomEE